# Multilingual Named Entity Linking

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis, named-entity-recognition

I am working on a clustering algorithm to cluster news articles from different sources into one event similar to what Google News does. Everything is working well, except for one problem.

I am clustering Arabic news articles, and the algorithm is working very good, it is showing very good results on Politics and Sports articles, but when it comes to Games and Technology, the results are not that good. The problem is I am having a very low recall (fewer clusters than should have).

After investigating, I found that the problem is with named entities. In Games and Tech, authors seem to be mixing between using English names, or Arabic equivalent name, and this is affecting the title terms weighing the most, which affect the final results in general.

Now, I am looking for a way to find equal named entities even if they are in different languages. I still don't know how exactly, and I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at "wikifiers":

- http://babelnet.org
- https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBpedia_Spotlight
- http://nerd.eurecom.fr
- ...

These tools generally rely more or less on dbpedia, which provides links between languages. Another solution would be to download language versions of dbpedia and extract name variants accross languages: more work, but probably faster and more relevant.